# How to select a single value in DB

Tags: php, select

I want to select a single value not an array,
so I use

```
$user = "SELECT Name FROM Manager WHERE Statue = 1";
echo "<ul id='man-nav' class='navline pull-right'><li><a href='#'>".$user."</a></li></ul>";
```

or I tried

```
$user = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Name FROM Manager WHERE Statue = 1");
echo "<ul id='man-nav' class='navline pull-right'><li><a href='#'>".$user."</a></li></ul>";
```

both are not correct, I am just not sure which function to take this value.

Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Is there only a single record with `Statue = 1` in the DB? What are getting as a result that is not what you expect?

Comment: yes it must has only one record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs on `mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), you will get a [`mysql_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) upon success, so you can either use [`mysqli_result::fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) or [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). Something similar to:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT Name FROM manager WHERE Statue = 1');
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo $row['Name'];
}
```

Comment: Hi sry I am not quite familiar with php, and the codes are not work, it says " Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"...

Comment: You're mixing global functions with methods. mysqli_ functions will produce resources, not mysqli objects. You'll need mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Comment: Yes, you could of course go procedural instead. Something more like: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: If you use `mysqli_query()`, you'll have to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, because the function won't return an object. If you used the `object->query()`, it'll return an object you can `->fetch_assoc()`. Right?

Comment: No, that's not right. Regardless of whether `mysqli_query()` is called procedurally or as a method it will return a `mysqli_result` object which itself can be accessed either procedurally or not.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* use PDO instead of mysql(i) functions and then you can use [fetchcolumn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Obviously this is just my opinion.

I say *should* because PDO is very safe (no more SQL injection!) and it's one interface for all drivers: easy. It also adds easy features like fetchColumn() and the class is easily extendable. Using 1 object for all db access is so much easier. Invest 20 minutes now and forever enjoy.

Comment: I think "should" could be a little much. There is nothing wrong with `mysqli_*` calls at all.

Comment: I agree with @Tigger MySQLi is perfectly fine and simpler to get started with.

Comment: It's really not perfectly fine and actually a bad way to learn IMO. PDO handles all security issues etc. People using mysql(i)_* functions tend to forget. SQL injection is still the # 1 security flaw. PDO takes care of that.

Comment: @Rudie hang on, it's like you haven't read the `mysql_*` deprecation notice. PDO and MySQLi have identical security measures and both support prepared statements. PDO supports named parameters and emulated prepares, and throws errors on failure (with `PDO::ERROR_ATTR`). Neither is less secure.

Comment: I can't believe anyone with any experience would root **for** using global functions... It's not bad or necessarily less secure, but you know it's less simple. That's why I think you _should_. That doesn't make it a bad answer, does it?

Comment: hi does this need to be that complex? my bad I can't understand that many functions... I thought it should be an easy function to solve out...

Comment: Nope, doesn't have to be complex. You can use 1 mysqli_ function and voila. Or take some time to learn PDO (or another abstraction layer) and reap the benefits forever. Just my opinion. =)

Comment: I'm not rooting for either way (actually, i'm rooting for PDO; it's far superior for all levels), but you appear to have confused ext/mysql (which is horribly outdated, deprecated and ancient) and ext/mysqli, which has had an OOP interface for ages and looks like "My First Database Object". It's not that mysqli is less safe (in fact, you are just as vulnerable to SQL Injection with either if you use native interfaces), it's that PDO is easier to use. @JamesChen PDO is very very easy to pick up and is far easier to use safely than mysqli, provided you know OOP.

Comment: @Hiroto Yes, use the MySQLi class. Do that. Not the functions. Enough of this.

Comment: hi thanks guys, my bad I am just a starter and self-studying. I appreciate ur guys' helping, plz dont make conflict :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is closer to being correct.

After running the query, you need to retrieve the values.

**I strongly suggest that you go through the documentation and examples at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php**